# Why unordered_set doesn't allow vector as key?

Tags: c++, c++11, set, std

For example:

```
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
unordered_set<vector<int>> s;
s.insert(v);
```

will gives error

> no match for call to '(const std::hash >) (const
>   std::vector&)'   noexcept(declval()(declval()))>

Comment: A vector can contain lots of types, so it's hard to generalize a hash function for it. And there's not much call for it.

Comment: You can supply your own hash function, but depending on your data it's likely not trivial to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Because [most of the C++ containers don't](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)? `vector<bool>` appears to have an explicit specialization, but that's the unusual case; typically, they didn't provide `std::hash` overloads for aggregate or collection types (possibly because they didn't want to lock in a hash combining algorithm applicable to arbitrary templated types).